# Why cannot catch events retrospectively using filter (eth_newFilter)?

Tags: json-rpc, events, python, testrpc, filters

I've put the same filter with `eth_newFilter` before and after a set of transactions. The one which is installed after transactions catched 0 events. Is it how events work? Is there any other way to catch events retrospectively except `eth_getLogs`?

```
from ethjsonrpc import EthJsonRpc
c = EthJsonRpc('127.0.0.1', 8545)
ADDRESS = "0xdb1154368ba2645e6c090f3d1f3ddd5c8c1f8008"
params = {
    "fromBlock": "0x01",
    "address": ADDRESS
}
before = c.eth_newFilter(params)
for i in range(100):
    tx = c.call_with_transaction(c.eth_coinbase(), ADDRESS, 'setValue(uint32)', [i])
    receipt = c.eth_getTransactionReceipt(tx)
after = c.eth_newFilter(params)

print len(c.eth_getFilterLogs(before)) // 100
print len(c.eth_getFilterLogs(after)) // 0
print len(c.eth_getLogs(params)) // 100
```

I'm using testrpc as blockchain client.

Comment: Is there a reason `eth_getLogs()` cannot be used? It has almost the same call signature as `eth_newFilter`.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa this is exact same question I'm typing right now. [Why use filters at all?))](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8069/why-use-filters-eth-getlogs-vs-eth-newfilter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TestRPC doesn't support past events unfortunately. You could try using a private Geth chain as detailed [here](https://souptacular.gitbooks.io/ethereum-tutorials-and-tips-by-hudson/content/private-chain.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! I suspected this, but couldn't find in the docs. Is it the same for filter topics? As I cannot make them work too.

Comment: + this answer helped me. Would you happen to know the answer to my question on filters: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/22954/mistake-when-using-web3-eth-filter-and-filter-get