# Why use filters - eth_getLogs vs eth_newFilter

Tags: json-rpc, events, python, testrpc, filters

It seems to me `eth_getLogs` is much simpler than `eth_newFilter` + `eth_getFilterLogs`.

`eth_getLogs` has no need for installation, got same parameters, catches events retrospectively. What are use cases of filters at all?

As in my previous [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8065/why-cannot-catch-events-retrospectively-using-filter-eth-newfilter?noredirect=1#comment8050_8065):

```
from ethjsonrpc import EthJsonRpc
c = EthJsonRpc('127.0.0.1', 8545)
ADDRESS = "0xdb1154368ba2645e6c090f3d1f3ddd5c8c1f8008"
params = {
        "fromBlock": "0x01",
        "address": ADDRESS
    }
before = c.eth_newFilter(params)
for i in range(100):
    tx = c.call_with_transaction(c.eth_coinbase(), ADDRESS, 'setValue(uint32)', [i])
    receipt = c.eth_getTransactionReceipt(tx)
after = c.eth_newFilter(params)

print len(c.eth_getFilterLogs(before)) // 100
print len(c.eth_getFilterLogs(after)) // 0
print len(c.eth_getLogs(params)) // 100
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`eth_getLogs`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/blob/78990aca283f67ceb26ed70c8eb82008424aaf64/JSON-RPC.md#eth_getlogs) returns an array of filter logs. You pass in the parameters - e.g. fromBlock, toBlock, etc. - you want to discriminate against. These are the same parameter used by [`eth_newFilter`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/blob/78990aca283f67ceb26ed70c8eb82008424aaf64/JSON-RPC.md#eth_newfilter).

`eth_newFilter` takes the same parameters, but returns a `filterId` instead of an array of logs. This ID can then be passed to [`eth_getFilterLogs`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/blob/78990aca283f67ceb26ed70c8eb82008424aaf64/JSON-RPC.md#eth_getfilterlogs), which returns the array of logs.

So far, so similar.

However, the `filterID` allows you to also use [`eth_getFilterChanges`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/blob/78990aca283f67ceb26ed70c8eb82008424aaf64/JSON-RPC.md#eth_getfilterchanges), which is a:

> Polling method for a filter, which returns an array of logs which
>   occurred since last poll.

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/fed692f67e81bd3937a5efab38f56a9b99d04d41/eth/filters/api.go#L561), giving a filter an ID better allows for this polling feature because it provides a key against which we can store the last time the filter was checked.

If you don't care about polling, then you probably just want `eth_getLogs`.

Comment: where does this `id` is stored? what if I'm talking to infura which is cluster of nodes and my id could be lost?

Comment: Infura doesn't support filters, and more specifically any of the following operations:
* eth_coinbas
* eth_sign
* eth_sendTransaction
* eth_newFilter
* eth_newBlockFilter
* eth_newPendingTransactionFilter
* eth_uninstallFilter
* eth_getFilterChanges
* eth_getFilterLogs
* db_putString
* db_getString
* db_putHex
* db_getHex